# couchbase primary index for bucket with '-' in the name

Tags: couchbase, sql++

While creating index I get this error:

```
[
  {
    "code": 3000,
    "msg": "syntax error - at -",
    "query_from_user": "create primary index on sample-partner"
  }
]
```

If I change the bucket name to sample_partner, then it works. Using Couchbase 4.5 Enterprise edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah that's because N1QL will interpret the `-` as a minus sign... You simply need to escape the bucket name using backquotes:

```
CREATE PRIMARY INDEX ON `sample-partner`;
```

It should work that way. Remember to always escape that bucket name in all N1QL queries and you should be fine. Or use the underscore in the bucket name, as an alternative :)

Comment: It's not a "limitation" :)

Comment: Limitation sounds a bit strong, reworded